# Taking the square root of this expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This expression is written under a radical and I need to take it out.

How to take the square root?

Simply calculate this:

$$\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (0<a\le b\le c)$$

Comment: Are you asking how to solve $\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}$?

Comment: Yes. taking square root = $\sqrt{}$

Comment: This is four times the area of a triangle of sides a, b, c (formula of Heron) when it is possible a triangle with these sides. If not, you get a non real number. If you have integer numbers a, b, c you possible can simplify common factors but if not you have to obey the friend BlueSky.

Comment: @BlueSky: Yeah, well, that statement wasn't their when you initially posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}$

Let's consider the radicand.

$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)$ can be written as $((a+b)+c)((a+b)-c)((a-b)+c)(-((a-b)-c))$

Now, by the equality $(x+y)(x-y)=(x^2-y^2)$, which we call (*) from now on, we can write the above expression as:

$-((a+b)^2-c^2)((a-b)^2-c^2)$. Developping, we get:
$-(a^2+b^2+2ab-c^2)(a^2+b^2-2ab-c^2)$.
By regrouping the terms we obtain
$-((a^2+b^2-c^2)+2ab)((a^2+b^2-c^2)-2ab)$. Again, by the equality (*), we can say that this equals $-((a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2)$. You see that the root of this exists if and only if $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2\leq 0$ so equivalently if $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2\leq (2ab)^2$. Now you have to discuss the cases, for which $a,b,c$ this condition is fullfilled.

EDIT: After you added the hypothesis that $(0<a\le b\le c)$, it is easier to treat the different cases.

We want:
$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2\leq (2ab)^2\\
$$
Let's denote the inequality above by (A).

From the [triangle inequalitiy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), it follows that $c\leq a+b$.

**Case 1: $c=a+b$**

In this case we have that $a^2+2ab+b^2=c^2$ which implies that 
$a^2+b^2-c^2=2ab$. Replacing $a^2+b^2-c^2$ by $2ab$ in $$\sqrt{-((a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2)}$$ gives us $$\sqrt{-((2ab)^2-(2ab)^2)}$$ which equals $\sqrt{-0}$ i.e. $0$.

**Case 2: $c<a+b$**

Then we can have that $c^2=a^2+b^2$ (Case 2.1) or $c^2<a^2+b^2$ (Case 2.2). It is impossible to have $c^2>a^2+b^2$ because $a, b$ and $c$ are all positive and  the function $f: [0, +\infty]\to [0, +\infty]$, $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing.

**Case 2.1: $c^2=a^2+b^2$**

Replacing in $$\sqrt{-((a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2)}$$ gives us
$$\sqrt{-((a^2+b^2-(a^2+b^2))^2-(2ab)^2)}= \sqrt{-(-(2ab)^2)}= \sqrt{(2ab)^2}= 2ab$$ because $a,b > 0$

**Case 2.2: $c^2<a^2+b^2$**

This implies that $a^2+b^2-c^2>0$. We also know that $2ab>0$.

Now, we can say that $a-b\leq 0$ since $a\leq b$. By this, we can conclude that $a-b< c$. In addition, we have $$0<a\le b\le c \iff b-a\le c-a<c \iff -c < a-b$$ so finally $$-c<a-b<c \iff (a-b)^2<c^2 \iff a^2 -2ab + b^2 < c^2 \iff a^2+b^2-c^2 < 2ab$$

Since both members of the last inequality are positive, we can conclude that we have the requested inequality (A), namely $$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2\leq (2ab)^2\\
$$

which was our necessary condition that $\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}$ exists. However, opposed to the other cases, I don't think that $\sqrt{-((a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2)}$ can be written in a more simplified way in Case 2.2.

I hope that I could help. Don't hesitate to ask further questions,

derthomas

Comment: derthomas see the edit.